# MySQL - How to Group by values and display in different colulmn on the same row

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

I have source table that I would like to sum quantities based on a specific value and display the sum for each value while grouping by an id.

```
animal_id oh co gender
10        5   1   M
20        10  5   F
10        15  2   F
30        5   0   C
10        5   4   M
20        10  0   F
```

I need an output of

```
animal_id Moh Mco Foh Fco Coh Cco
10        10  5   15  2   0   0
20        0   0   20  5   0   0
30        0   0   0   0   5   0
```

Each column will display the sum of each gender and each row will be grouped by the animal_id.

I tried to use the CASE like is MSSQL but it didn't sum per each gender.
Thinking PIVOT but I'm not very familiar with it.
I'm at a loss...

Comment: Pivot is on the right track. Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: I haven't tried the pivot because I was told MySQL doesn't have pivot like MSSQL, and I'm not familiar with pivot in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
SELECT animal_id, 
SUM(IF(gender='M', oh, 0)) AS Moh, SUM(IF(gender='M', co, 0)) AS Mco, 
SUM(IF(gender='F', oh, 0)) AS Foh, SUM(IF(gender='F', co, 0)) AS Fco, 
SUM(IF(gender='C', oh, 0)) AS Coh, SUM(IF(gender='C', co, 0)) AS Cco
FROM anim_table
GROUP BY animal_id;
```

So key concept is to combine `SUM()` with `IF()`

Comment: Ah, nice method. Let me try this. Thanks!

Comment: @CasyChoate you are welcome. if works, dont forget to accept my answer :D

Comment: Well, I think you just solved my problem. Thank you so much, that gave me the right outcome.